# Elixir Pass parameter into Plug for previous plug parameter

Tags: elixir, plug

This may not be a Breadcrumble question, but how do I pass a parameter from a previous plug into the breadcrumbable? For example, if the previous plug `set_merchant` sets the merchant on `conn.params.merchant`, how can I pass that `id` to breadcrumable?

```
   plug :set_merchant
   plug :add_breadcrumb, name: "Dashboard", url: "/dashboard/#{conn.params.merchant_id}"
```

.....

```
 defp set_merchant(conn, _opt) do
    case conn.params do
      %{"merchant_id" => merchant_id} ->
        case MyApp.find_merchant(merchant_id) do
          nil ->
            conn |> redirect(to: "/dashboard/#{merchant_id}") |> halt
          merchant ->
            assign(conn, :merchant, merchant)
        end
      _ ->
        conn |> redirect(to: "/") |> halt
    end
  end
```

The `conn.params.merchant_id` is where I would want to pass the param from the first plug `set_merchant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [`add_breadcrumb` plug](https://github.com/ma2gedev/breadcrumble_ex/blob/1a2979ff3e4e0e05c3ec0a6ba997e62dc049a6d9/lib/breadcrumble/plugs.ex#L2) directly from the `set_merchant` plug like this:

```
assign(conn, :merchant, merchant)
|> Breadcrumble.Plugs.add_breadcrumb(name: "Dashboard", url: "/dashboard/#{merchant_id}")
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It was the simplest way, although I don't think my original question was answered but at the same time, I don't think it is possible to do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass as many parameters as you want as you do already with `Plug.Conn.assign/3` function.

The simplest solution for you is to do something like this in your `case`:

```
case MyApp.find_merchant(merchant_id) do
  nil ->
    conn 
    |> redirect(to: "/dashboard/#{merchant_id}") 
    |> halt()
  merchant ->
    conn
    |> assign(:merchant, merchant)
    |> assign(:merchant_id, merchant_id) # this is what you asked for
end
```

Then you will not call your `plug` by adding this `url` with `merchant_id`, because the conn would already have it because `set_merchant` would provide it to you.

Also, another option:

If you don't want to have `merchant_id` there, you can simply get it from `merchant`, by doing:

```
merchant_id = conn.assigns.merchant.id
```

You have to differentiate `params` from `assigns`. I'm not sure how do you get the `merchant`, but to remember this quickly:

- `params` come from the outside e.g. POST request, query strings etc.
- `assigns` are set by you or anyone else who modified `Plug.Conn` with `assign/3` function

Comment: The issue is that on the `plug :add_breadcrumb` i cannot access the `conn`. I can assign it just fine in the `set_merchant` function, but then we need to pass the `id` of the merchant into the `plug :add_breadrecrumb` url parameter